# Property 'AppBrowserModule' must be followed by a ':' Angular 6 Universal

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I've suddenly gotten this error in my application whilst trying to deploy to heroku

```
ERROR in Module build failed: 
   import { AppBrowserModule } from '.././src/app/app.browser.module';
           ^
         Property "AppBrowserModule" must be followed by a ':'
         in /tmp/build_7644f49ade809e431a37378b78d5aaeb/src/main.ts (line 1, column 10)
```

I've never seen this error before below is my main.ts

```
import { AppBrowserModule } from '.././src/app/app.browser.module';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppBrowserModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

does anyone have any ideas what could be the issue?

I don't get why AppBrowserModule must be followed by a `:`

**UPDATE**

changed path to

```
import { AppBrowserModule } from './app/app.browser.module';
```

and still getting this error

```
import { AppBrowserModule } from './app/app.browser.module';
           ^
         Property "AppBrowserModule" must be followed by a ':'
         in /tmp/build_50914abeca937c3d51cd4592171d1581/src/main.ts (line 1, column 10)
```

Comment: please try import like this - `import { AppBrowserModule } from '../../src/app/app.browser.module';`

Comment: @PardeepJain I have updated my answer with and it is still happening even after changing path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of removing snippets of code I seem to have found the issue,

I was using this in my `angular.json`

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            ...
          ]
        },
```

for some reason this breaks the angular-universal build.